# How to check progress of image upload to Firebase storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

When the user registers for my app they choose a profile picture, input a name, email, and password. I use firebase to authenticate them using email and password. I am using `FIRAuth.auth()?.addAuthStateDidChangeListener`  to detect the change in a user's authentication status. If the user has been authenticated the code inside executes (this code sends the user to the next viewController). The problem is that the code inside fires off before my data can be added to the realtime database and FirebaseStorage. Is there a way to monitor when both tasks have succeeded so then I can trigger the change of view controllers? Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firebase has a [tutorial](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/5-tips-for-firebase-storage.html) on how to track the progress of file uploaded to their servers:

```
let storageRef = FIRStorage.reference().child("folderName/file.jpg");
let localFile: NSURL = // get a file;

// Upload the file to the path "folderName/file.jpg"
let uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(localFile, metadata: nil)

let observer = uploadTask.observeStatus(.Progress) { snapshot in
  print(snapshot.progress) // NSProgress object
}
```

> This snapshot gives you useful information, such as the total size of
>   the file in bytes and how many bytes have been uploaded so far. Using
>   this information, you can calculate the percentage uploaded and use it
>   to update any UI control in your app.

Comment: I will be sure to take a look at this. I must have missed it when I was looking through their documentation.